# Bash looks for the wrong executable for man

Tags: bash, linux-mint, man

I recently installed TeX-Live and attempted to add its man to the manpath. It didn't work and couldn't find entries, and I didn't care too much. However, (I suppose) after a system restart, the `man` command isn't working altogether.

```
:~$ man man
bash: /mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/man: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I don't know why it is looking for the TeX Live's version.

```
:~$ whereis man
man: /usr/bin/man /usr/local/man /usr/share/man /mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/man /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz
```

I had modified both `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/manpath.config` based on [this accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60765/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-manpath-or-infopath), both of which I restored back. I tried `source`ing the new bashrc file, logging out and in, or restarting the system, but I cannot seem to get the `man` working again.

What is the problem here, how can I restore the `man`, and what can I be overlooking? To be clear, I don't care about successfully adding TeX Live to the man page, I just want to get my `man` command functional again.

---

**EDIT: Additional informations**

Here is the path variables: (I broke the output int multiple lines and erased colons to have it easier to read here.)

```
:~$ echo $PATH
/mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux
/home/<username>/.local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

The topmost one should be the one I need to build latex projects, so I suppose it shouldn't cause the problem.

Also, `echo $MANPATH` doesn't print anything.

When it comes to what I did, I didn't do anything but modifying these two files.

I added the following lines to `$HOME/.bashrc`

```
PATH=/mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

And then I added the following line at the end of the section `# set up PATH to MANPATH mapping` in the `/etc/manpath.config`

```
MANPATH_MAP /mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux    /mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

I then run `source ~/.bashrc`, and tried to access man pages of some random TeX stuff, and encoutered with a message stating that the related entry was not found. Hence, even though it wasn't working with TeX, the `man` command was functional still.

I believe I left it here, and noticed that the problem I described few days later. As I said, I undid everything I mentioned above.

Because some time has passed, and I didn't necessarily know what I was doing especially with the `manpath.config` file, I might have done something else, but I don't recall doing anything else. If you have suggestions of potential actions that can cause a problem like this, or a way of solving this regardless, (which doesn't involve reinstalling the linux or anything, of course) I will appreciate.

Comment: `type man` (or `type -a man`) will likely be more diagnostic as to what your bash shell is seeing than `whereis man`

Comment: @steeldriver It lists the first three results of `whereis man` in reverse order. I don't know what to do with that though.

Comment: Please add `echo "$PATH"` and its result to your question. Also explain how you "_attempted to add its man to the manpath_" (I see you've linked to a question, but please state here which commands you ran.) If you undo the changes you made you'll find it all works once more.

Comment: @roaima I edited the post, hopefully I provided necessary information, beyond that, even if I did something, which I probably didn't, I don't recall doing it. I feel like there should be an easy way of fixing this.

Comment: When you do `echo $PATH`, do you really get newlines between most of the directories, or have you edited the output? I would expect a list of `:`-delimited directory paths, not lines of directory paths.

Comment: @they I did edited it to have it more easily readable here. I should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: If you're running mint then install mint's own texlive packages.  Don't just run random binaries you downloaded off the net.  Even ignoring issues related to trust and security, if they're not compiled against the libs in mint, there's no guarantee that they'll work at all or, worse, they might work incorrectly.    Note: software developers often give instructions on how to install their pre-compiled binaries.  Following these instructions is almost always a bad idea.  Use the packages for your distro instead.

Comment: `apt-get install texlive`.   and maybe some of the related extras like `texlive-science` or `texlive-latex-extra` or some of the language or font packages.   Run `apt-cache search -n texlive` for a list of available packages.   and `apt-cache show packagename` for details on particular packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`MANPATH`" controls where the `man` command looks for `man` pages, if you want something unusual. Leave it unset to use the default locations. See `man man` when you get this fixed.

"`$PATH`" is a **colon-separated** list of directories where your shell looks for executable programs (if what you typed isn't an alias, function, or builtin).
By placing the `/mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` first in your `PATH`, you're letting `texlive` provide the (non-working) `man` command. See `man bash` when fixed.
Put `texlive` at the end of `PATH`. Change the `.bashrc` line to:

```
PATH=$PATH:/mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux
```

And logout/login to start fresh.

For more detail on using the "colon-separated" list as a `bash` datatype, I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

Comment: If the tex `man` command has the wrong architecture / is missing libraries / plain isn't working, then it's likely that none of the commands will work. So just remove the directory from `$PATH` completely

Comment: @roaima Actually `latexmk` was working before I started messing with the manpath and I was able to build tex files. Although now after changing the bashrc content as shown above, it decided not to. Frankly I have no idea how I ended up here.

Comment: Well, I suspect I slightly corrupted my hard drive as I did a disk level restoration from a Windows machine shortly after installing texlive for irrelevant reasons, I think this is why I get binary errors. Not that it matters at this point nor is it related the question, still wanted to state that in case you are wondering how I managed this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line to restore your executables:

```
PATH=/mnt/HDD/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
```

Remove the other two lines to restore the documentation search paths for `man` and `info` respectively.